# How can I use ormlite to escape my insert?

Tags: ormlite, sql-insert

I have ormlite integrated into an application I'm working on. Right now I'm trying to build in functionality to easily switch from automatically inserting data to the database to outputting the equivalent collection of insert statements to a file for later use. The data isn't user input but still requires proper escaping to handle basic gotchas like apostrophes.

Ideas I've burned through:

- `Dao.create()` writes to the database directly, so that's a no-go.
- `QueryBuilder` can't handle inserts.
- `JdbcDatabaseConnection.compileStatement()` might work but the amount of setup required is inappropriate.
- Using a `java.sql.PreparedStatement` has a reasonable enough interface (if `toString()` returns the SQL like I would hope) but it's not compatible with ormlite's connection types.

This should be very easy and if it is, I can't find the right combination of method calls to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I'm trying to build in functionality to easily switch from automatically inserting data to the database to outputting the equivalent collection of insert statements to a file for later use.

Interesting.  So one hack would be to use the `MappedCreate` class.  The `MappedCreate.build(...)` method takes a `DatabaseType` and a `TableInfo` which is available from the `dao.getTableInfo()`.

The `mappedCreate.toString()` exposed the generated `INSERT` statement (with a prefix) which might help but you would still need to convert the `?` arguments to be the actual values with escaped quotes.  That you would have to do in your own code.

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Escaping the values is the kind of code I was hoping to avoid writing. are you saying I'd still need to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see how you are going to have insert statements in a text file without it @phasetwenty.